# how to use ModelState.IsValid in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's say I have a `Employee` class whose name field has to be string, but in the form submitted name is number 123 for example, I saw code like this:

```
UpdateModel(employee);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   employeeBusinessLayer.SaveEmployee(employee);

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I don't quite understand how to use `ModelState.IsValid` here, I mean when it calls:

```
UpdateModel(employee);
```

It will throw an exception since employee's name can't be a number, if it doesn't throw exceptions, it means the model is valid, so why we still use `ModelState.IsValid`? Why not just use try catch block?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: It's hard to see how you're using `UpdateModel(...)` - could you please provide more information about the action around your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

To provide error message, Display name and specific string formats.

```
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage="{0}'s length should be between {2} and {1}.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/

Answer (score 0):

You have to decorate a RegularExpression on a Name property to allow only characters.

```
[RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z]+)", ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets  for Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid tells you if any model errors have been added to ModelState.

It also depends upon various scenario.
if i want to bind four properties of model out of 6 then i will remove error from model state and do update model.
otherwise if i want to validate  all  properties then  i will use ModelState.IsValid first and on the basis of that result we will do next operations.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
//Handle the error here, if needed
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your Validation Message");
}
```

And as other's have said, you would decorate the properties in your model (or view model) if you want .net to handle the validations for you.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid just checks if the model you are using has passed the Data Annotations that you added to the properties. For example, you can add the [Required] annotation to one of our model properties. Then, ModelState.IsValid will validate against that. If you don't add any data annotations to your model, then, yes, the ModelState.IsValid won't be much help.

However, you can also add your own errors to the ModelState using the ModelState.AddError method inside your controller action. This is useful, since .Net will handle all the errors and stuff for you, provided you are using the built in validation methods. So, you could use ModelState.AddError, and then return the View. If your view is handling errors, such as having a Validation Summary, then it will show the error you added.